# Laravel whereNull and where clause returns empty object

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm new to laravel. I tried to fetch some records from my database which are "parent" column is "null". But it returns always
empty object. Then I got the query using toSql() function and ran it manually on database. Query works fine. Why laravel returns nothing?

laravel version is : 8.1.0

here is my model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'child_level',
        'type',
        'meta_url',
        'meta',
        'parent'
   ];

    public function teacher() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
           Teacher::class,
           'category_teachers',
           'category_id',
           'teacher_id',
         );
    }
}
```

here is my function in controller

```
public function mainCourses() {
    $main_courses = Category::whereNull('parent');
    if (isset($main_courses)) {
        return response(['main_courses' => $main_courses], 200);
    }
    return response(['message' => 'No main courses in database'] , 404);
}
```

this is the database table

[image: this is the database table]

when i call to the method it returns response like this.

[image]

I want to return all the records with 'parent' column is 'null'.
what is the wrong with this? is there an other way to do this? Help me...

Comment: that is what a `NULL` suppose to do, it wont show you anything. if you need to show the `NULL` string, do a checking. if it is `NULL` then show the string `NULL`.

Comment: Unfamiliar with Laravel, but [aren't you supposed](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses) to do something like `$main_courses = DB::table('category')->whereNull('parent')->get();` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $main_courses = Category::whereNull('parent');

`$main_courses` in this case will be just a query builder

you should get the result from DB using get() function

```
$main_courses = Category::whereNull('parent')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works. But i want to know why i can run ::find() without  -> get and where clause expects that?

Comment: https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_find

Comment: find expect the id , and return only one record, it is not helpful in your case

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$mainCourse = Category::whereNull('parent')->get();

if (!empty($mainCourse)) {
    return response(['main_courses' => $main_courses], 200);
 }

 return response(['message' => 'No main courses in database'] , 404);
```